# i dont understand why my "if" command don't work as it should

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random  
cde = random.random()  
print(cde)  
tst = input("Whats the code?\n")  
if tst == cde:  
    print("Welcome")  
else:  
    print("Imposter!!!")
```

when i run this code and after I've typed in the "cde" thing its keeps saying imposter but it should say welcome

Comment: `tst` is str, while `cde` is float

Comment: No one asked about what python version Abdul is using. The input in Python version 3.0 is different from older implementations.

Comment: seeing that he uses `input` and not `raw_input` makes clear that this is python 3...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist No, it is not clear that he uses python 3: `input()` does exist in Python 2, `raw_input()` is just the better choice in many cases because `input()` in Python 2 automatically tries to evaluate the input as python code.

Comment: ooops. you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

random returns a `float` that you are comparing with a `string` from the user input - they will never be equal...

you could try:

```
import random  
cde = str(round(random.random(), 3))
print(cde)  
tst = input("Whats the code?\n")        # <- python3
# tst = raw_input("Whats the code?\n")  # <- python2
if tst == cde:  
    print("Welcome")  
else:  
    print("Imposter!!!")
```

and in order to avoid rounding effects you may consider rounding the result from `random.random()`.

note the different ways of getting user input depending on the python version you are using.

Comment: This assumes the use of Python 3. With Python 2, `input()` will return a float if the input is a valid representation of a float in Python (e.g. `.0123`, `321.`, `123.456`, `123E4`, `1.234e5`).

Answer (score 1):

[Random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) will return an float, whereas you are reading from [STDIN](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) an string, you need to cast them to a common type:

```
import random  
cde = random.random()  
print(cde)  
tst = input("Whats the code?\n")  
if str(tst) == str(cde):  // cast to a common type, string or a long, float
    print("Welcome")  
else:  
    print("Imposter!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not casting so in this case you are comparing a string to a long. Simple fix (python 2 only):

```
import random  
cde = random.random()  
print(cde)  
tst = input("Whats the code?\n")  
if long(tst) == long(cde):  
    print("Welcome")  
else:  
    print("Imposter!!!")
```

Comment: this will not work as expected: `random.random()` returns a `float` in [0,1)... https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random

Comment: tested it with float and it fails since it truncates the input number down odly I am aware it returns a float just printing its type gives that away nonethless that does not work. But if you think about it  using long should work you are casting both of them to long which has more storage space so no rounding down will happen if both of them were floats. Tried it several times and it seems to work, I can upload a unit test if you need convincing ?

Comment: you are right about the rounding but: python 3 does no longer have `long`; just `int` and casting a `float` in  [0,1) to an `int` will always return 0.

Comment: yeah I would not consider casting it to int. Updated the post to python 2 only. The string alternative is definitely the most easy going one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work this way:
str(tst) == str(cde)

Answer (score 0):

The issue depends on your version of Python:

- For Python 2.x the issue is that

  ```
  print(cde)
  ```

  prints only the first 12 decimal digits of `cde`. So if you just type that for `tst` it will in most cases not match as there are several more digits, you just do not see. You can test this in an interactive Python session:

  ```
  >>> import random
  >>> a = random.random()
  >>> a
  0.10981364144091466
  >>> print a
  0.109813641441
  ```
- For Python 3.x the issue is that with

  ```
  cde = random.random()
  ```

  `cde` is of type `builtins.float`, while with

  ```
  tst = input("Whats the code?\n")
  ```

  `tst` is of type `builtins.str`. So comparing these two will always return `False`.

An additional issue is that comparing floats for equality (`==`) is not always reliable. The printed decimal value does not exactly match the internal binary value.

I would suggest generating a random integer and casting the input also to integer:

```
import random  
cde = int(random.random() * 1000000)
print(cde)  
tst = int(input("Whats the code?\n"))
if tst == cde:  
    print("Welcome")  
else:  
    print("Imposter!!!")
```

This code work with Python 2.x and 3.x, but for Python 2.x it would be a good idea to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. You could just use `str()` instead of `int()`, but using integers instead of casting to `str` has the benefit that you also could easily make numerical lesser/greater comparisons.